# Search for users can't get it to work with ms graph java SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

What I'm trying to do works fine through the graph explorer, and even copying the URL from my logs works too:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?%24search=%22displayName%3Adummy%22&%24select=id%2CdisplayName&%24orderby=displayName

Expected result:

Returns only matching users containing dummy in their display name

Actual result:

Matches all users in directory

```java
        final OkHttpClient graphHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(authProvider)
                .newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();

        DefaultLogger defaultLogger = new DefaultLogger();
        defaultLogger.setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

        GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .logger(defaultLogger)
                .httpClient(graphHttpClient)
                .buildClient();
        LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<>();
        requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$search", "\"displayName:dummy\""));
        UserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
                .buildRequest(requestOptions)
                .select("id,displayName")
                .orderBy("displayName")
                .get();

        users.getCurrentPage(); // contains all users in my directory, not just the searched one
```

Maven co-ordinates:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core-http-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Try to add a header "ConsistencyLevel" = eventual. It worked for me.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma thanks that was it, do you want to post it as an answer? 

```
requestOptions.add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
```

There's a bug in the Graph Explorer code generation as it doesn't add this header, (although the header tab does include it which I missed)

Comment: Yes, I agree Tim. Code snippets doesn't give correct code sometimes.  Add as Answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a header `"ConsistencyLevel" = "eventual"` to get it to work.